# Syntax error, MySQL alter column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add referential integrity to a column. However, I can't know the proper syntax for an alter statement. I've attempted the below code. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
alter table person_address modify column address_addressID int(11) not null,
on update cascade;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Not null` has nothing to do with referential integrity. If you want to *require* an address ID here, that's separate from adding a foreign key link to the Address table.

```
alter table person_address modify column address_addressID int(11) not null;
```

That statement means you MUST have a value in this column. That's all it means; nothing more or less.

To link this table to the Address table (assuming that is the table's name), you need this:

```
ALTER TABLE person_address 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (address_addressID)
REFERENCES address_tbl_name (addressID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I've no idea what the primary key field is named or what that table looks like, so replace address_tbl_name and addressID in line 3 with appropriate field/table name.